# Batch normalization とバッチサイズについて

Tags: tensorflow, keras

現在、Tensorflow+Kerasでモデルの学習をおこなっています。
このモデルにはBatch normalization　レイヤーが含まれています。
ただ、使用しているGPUのメモリが少ないため、バッチサイズが4くらいでしか学習できません。
このように、バッチサイズが小さい場合でもBatch normalizationはうまく機能するものなのでしょうか。
よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

バッチサイズを大きくできない場合のためのアルゴリズムもいくつか提案されています。

Layer Normalization: https://arxiv.org/abs/1607.06450
Group Normalization: https://arxiv.org/abs/1803.08494
Weight Standardization: https://arxiv.org/abs/1903.10520

TensorFlowでLayerNormalizationは提供されているようです。
https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/LayerNormalization

Comment: ありがとうございます！参考になります。ただ、やはりbatch normalization が圧倒的なんですね。。

Comment: BNは高性能で広く使われていますが、Group NormalizationとWeight Standardizationの組み合わせでBN超える場合もあるらしく、圧倒的ということもないんじゃないかと。 https://arxiv.org/abs/1903.10520 https://arxiv.org/abs/1912.11370